# Bootstrap Dropdown Button

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using Bootstrap 3, with Ruby on Rails and I'm having some issues with a dropdown button. The button does drop down and shows the list items, but upon clicking on one I'm taken to the top of the page and no list item was selected.

Here's the code for the dropdown button - html.erb file

```
   <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-12"> 
          <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
    How many?

  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2-9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">10+</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
        </div>
```

My knowledge of JS is non-existent so I've been looking at other people's questions but I'm still unable to work it out.

The script also in the html.erb file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
    });
</script>
```

When running the app the Javascript console throws up a 404 not found for bootstrap.js. I currently have the bootstrap under Vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js

Should the bootstrap JS files be under app/assets/javascripts?

Hopefully someone is able to shed some light on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You are confusing lists and menus I think. Your menu items are not doing anything special so you are effectively clicking the anchor, all of which link to `#`.

Comment: The dropdown button is part of a form, so the layout of the button looks fine. I can see what you are saying, but I'm still unable to click on one of the dropdown items to select it. Thanks for your input @DavidG

Comment: What do you mean by "select" the dropdown item? What exactly do you want to happen when you click on a menu item?

Comment: The item to take the place of the button title and for the selection to be submitted along with the form upon form submission. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to a href attribute problem in the "a" element. Remove a literal "#" and try again.

And all of loaded file path whatever you want to load from your local storage should be path for based on your local storage too. that is, apps/asset/javascript path is correct.

Comment: I fixed the problem with the asset path, I'm using Rails and I can never get img src to work for me, but the following code worked. `<%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap.js"%> `